# How to search for attribute Text with ' and " in XML

Tags: python, xml, special-characters, elementtree

I'm using Python and ElementTree

I have the problem that I have 2 xml-files, where I need to copy some information from one to the other. Therefore I have to search for with a string from the first xml-file inside the second xml-file
The problem is that this string can include every kind of character, also the characters ' and "

I wrote the following line for searching:

`slpRow = slpNode.find("row/[@id='%s']" % (tsSource))`

In this case I get errors when tsSource contains the character '

I can handle this by writing

`slpRow = slpNode.find('row/[@id="%s"]' % (tsSource))`

in that case, but this would lead to problems when having the character "

So my problem is the case, when tsSource contains " as well as '

Is there a way to handle such a case?

Changing the xml-files and use &#39 resp. &#34 is not an option, because the files are autogenerated and this merging is only one step in a chain

Thanks

EDIT:
To make it ome clear, this whole stuff is for a translation-tool

The XML string in the first XML-File would look like this:

`<tsSource>Peter said: "it is Frank's book""</tsSource>`

In the second XML, there is something like

```
<row id="Peter said: "it is Frank's book"">
   <lang id="de_DE">Peter sagte: "Es ist Frank's Buch"</lang>
</row>
```

The problem is, that I have to search for the string Peter said: "it is Frank's book"" in the second file, but either

`slpRow = slpNode.find('row/[@id="Peter said: "it is Frank's book""]')`

or

`slpRow = slpNode.find("row/[@id='Peter said: "it is Frank's book"']")`

is failing.

Error output is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 263, in iterfind
    selector = _cache[cache_key]
KeyError: ('row/[@id="Peter said: "it is Frank\'s book""]', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Tasks/59676 Automated translation tool/TranslationMerger.py", line 63, in <module>
    slpRow = slpNode.find('row/[@id="%s"]' % (tsSource))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 298, in find
    return next(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces), None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 277, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 233, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Comment: "I get errors". What errors exactly? How is `tsSource` created? It would be easier to help if you provided a proper [mcve].

Comment: `tsSoure` is the input from another XML-File:  `tsSource = tsMessage.find('source').text`

Comment: Yes, but can you please provide a [mcve] so we can test for ourselves?

Comment: I added some example to make it more clear (hopefully) what the problem is

Comment: The second XML is ill-formed. The attribute value delimiter for `id` is a double quote, and then there cannot be any double quotes in the attribute value. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21765139/407651